# Node translate tab access

Tags: i18n-l10n

Why translate tab only available for super Admin in node & taxonomy form.
how can i view this tab & also button of save & translate for both Node & Taxonomy
to another roles (Editors & Translators), what is the proper permission access
should be given to show the translation tab ?

Forget to mention, this happen only when the node or content is unpublished,
but if its published the tabs appear normally.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the not-super-admin users don't have permission to edit unpublished content that they didn't create.

If you want to alter this behavior you can add a new permission "edit any unpublished content" and use hook_node_access to allow editing unpublished nodes (if they have that permission)

Comment: The not-super-admin already can edit the unpublished content, but the problem is he/she can't translate it because the translate tab is not accessible if the content is unpublished, also is there a permission for edit Or translate unpublished content ?

Comment: From the translation.module code I can see that the translation link is visible **WHEN**: the node has a translation **AND** the node type supports translation **AND** the user has view access **AND** the user has the _'translate content'_ permission. If you believe your users are qualified for the above I suggest adding a few DPMs in the __translation_tab_access_ function in translation.module